# Swift's Optional Error in the Segue between Several ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift

### Error Description:

We always use `func prepareForSegue()` to pass data during using the Segue.  Let's hypothesis the situation:

A TableViewController Class, named `TableViewController`, contains some cells which can lead to another DetailViewController Class, named `DetailViewController`, with touching the specific cell.

My app-logic is `DetailViewController` shows a Image, which saves in the `Assets.xcassets` folder,  after touching the cell in the `TableViewController`. In the `funs prepareForSugue()`, which located in the Class `TableViewController`, I pass the Image to the instance of `DetailViewController`'s `imageView` property. (For now, please ignore the property named imageName in the Class `DetailViewController`)

The error occurred after I touched one cell, before the `DetailViewController`'s image showing up.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

### The Code:

TableViewController:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 0
 }
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        if identifier == "showDetailViewController" {
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
            destinationController.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "DefaultFood")
         }
      }
   }
}
```

DetailViewController:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

var imageName = ""
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageView.image = UIImage(name: imageName)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
}
```

### The Question:

Now, we can use the `imageName` property in the Class `DetailViewController`. If I only pass the image's name in the `func prepareForSegue()` through `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`, located in `TableViewController` and retrieve the `UIImage.image` in the `func viewDidLoad()`, located in `DetailViewController`. The APP worked with no problem and showed up the Image I want after I touched the cell.

By the way, the data-Array for tableViewDataDelegate was created and used in the AppDelegate.swift.

Modified `func prepareForSegue():`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        if identifier == "showRestaurantDetail" {
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
           if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                destinationController.imageName = self.delegate.restaurantData[indexPath.row].foodName
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I really don't know which variable in my code trigger the `Optional Error` due to the unexpected `nil` value. The same error occurred even I set up the optional binding syntax.

Why the App worked successful when I only pass the image's name ?

Does this mechanism only work out when the UIImage Property allocated in the it's own Class's method, `viewDidLoad() in the Class DetailViewController`, rather than the `func prepareForSegue()` in the `TableViewController`?

Please teach me how to understand this problem.

A big appreciation for your guide and time.

Ethan Joe

Comment: Is your `seque.destinationViewController` in `let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController` of the correct type and not `nil`? You could check that by using something like `if let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController` (I'm not sure whether there has to be a question mark with the `as`).

Comment: I think it is because the UIImageView is not allocated yet when you try and assign the image property on the segue.